# Android studio defaulting to Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just finished my Java module at Uni and was starting to experiment with Andriod studio.
I updated it today to Flamingo and started a new project, and now it is defaulting to Kotlin.

I've only just learnt java and wanting to use that, how do I get the MainActivity file to default to Java?

Help is much appreciated,
Thanks

G

Answer (score 3):

Choose for example the 'Empty Views Activity' as starting template when creating a new project. There you do have the option to choose Kotlin/Java.

The default template uses Compose, which is Kotlin only.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the right button to a directory where you want the activity to be created
2. New -> Activity -> Empty Activity
3. Here will be `Source Language`, just choose **Java** there